# Object is not valid as a a React Child

Tags: reactjs

This is my Node State screenshot:

https://gyazo.com/ac8ebbe5989cf1ff80aee5dba4786793

When I am mapping it like this:

```
  <  {this.state.nodes.map((node, index) => {
            const showbutton = node.className === 'square';
            const decisionbutton = node.className === 'diamond';
     return(
      <div
             key={index}
             className={'node ' + node.className}
             id={node.id}
             ref={nodes => this.refs.nodes[index] = nodes}
             style={node.style}
             onClick={this.activeElem}

         >

            {node.text}

             {showbutton
           ?  <div className="add-btn" onClick={event => this.editProcess(event, node,index)}>+</div>
           :  <p></p>
             }

             {decisionbutton
                 ? <div className="add-btn" onClick={event => this.editProcess(event, node, index)}>+</div>
                 : <p></p>
             }
        <div className="delete-btn" onClick={event=>this.deleteNode(event,node)}>X</div>
      </div>
            )
       })}>
```

at {node.text} I am getting the error that object is not valid as a React Child

I tried this way to overcome this problem but nothing helps:

```
     {(node.text|| []).map((child,key)=>{
               return (
                  <div key={key}>
                  {child.text}
               </div>
            );
         })}
```

Comment: Instead of using `{child.text}` in your last example, simply use `{child}`

Comment: I am getting the error that the node.text.map is not a function

Comment: `text` is an array of arrays, in which in turn each object has a `text` property that is another array. Maybe you could change your data structure somewhat?

Comment: use { JSON.stringify(node.text) } to see the content and rid the error... after you can decide what you need to do

Comment: I am getting this 

`[[{"textid":"d25b79f0-6102-11e9-9582-69f183bfc265","text":["asads"]}]]`

I want to show the Text

Comment: @Joaozito Polo I am getting this

`[[{"textid":"d25b79f0-6102-11e9-9582-69f183bfc265","text":["asads"]}]]`
 when i am doing JSON.stringify(node.text) I want to show text inside text array

Answer (score 0):

Your text field has an array with an inner array, so try to render the array directly it's throwing the error. Modified the code trying by you as below, please check.

```
 {Array.isArray(node.text) ? node.text.map((child,key)=>{
               return (
                  <div key={key}>
                  {child && child.length > 0 ? child[0].text.join(' ') : ''}
               </div>
            );
         }) : node.text}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help bro but its showing me this error

TypeError: (node.text || []).map is not a function

Comment: Please post your sample json bro

Comment: This is my sample Json 

https://gyazo.com/ac8ebbe5989cf1ff80aee5dba4786793

Comment: I think there is a problem with your code changing the value for text key. Please check that too. I have edited the answer also, please check it.